# Show that $\psi \circ \phi$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\phi : G_1 \to G_2$ and $\psi : G_2 \to G_3$ be isomorphisms. Show that $\phi ^{-1}$ and $\psi \circ \phi$ are both isomorphisms. Using these results, show that the isomorphism of groups determines an equivalence relation on the class of all groups.

I was able to show that $\phi ^{-1}$ is an isomorphism (since $\phi$ is an isomorphism (i.e. a bijection), then the inverse exists and is also a bijection, so it's an isomorphism).

However, I'm unsure of how to show $\psi \circ \phi$ is an isomorphism. I haven't learned about homomorphisms yet, and I've seen a lot of answers using them to solve this question.

Answer (score 1):

If $\phi $ and $\psi$ are bijections so is $\psi \circ \phi$. If these are homomorphisms then $(\psi \circ \phi) (gg') =\psi (\phi(g) \phi (g'))=\psi (\phi(g)) \psi (\phi(g'))=(\psi \circ \phi) (g)(\psi \circ \phi) (g')$. Hence $\psi \circ \phi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I haven't learned about homomorphisms in my class yet, so is there another way to show this?

Comment: What is your definition of an isomorhism?

Comment: If G and H are groups and f: H --> G is an isomorphism, then $f^{-1}$ is an isomorphism, the order of G equals the order of H, G is abelian if and only if H is abelian, G is cyclic if and only if H is cycle, and G has a subgroup of order n if and only if H has a subgroup of order n.

Comment: Also, an isomorphism exists if the function is bijective

Comment: This doesn't really define an isomorphism - it just gives consequences of $f$ being an isomorphism.

Comment: If you do not know the defintion of an isomorphism this question cannot be answered. Please study homomorphisms and isomorphisms from any book on group theory.